# .jar application not working properly

Tags: macos, java

I recently installed MARS MIPS Simulator and the issue I am facing is that when I save a file and then try to reopen it later, the pop up window which shows the files available to open is blank even though there are multiple files present which can be opened.

[image]

Comment: What version of macos and java are you using?

Comment: I am using Java version 15 and macos Catalina